# How to display array in xml file with Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, xml

I've successfully parsed an XML file using Swift in XCode, the issue is displaying an array within it.

Here is a sample of the XML file:

```
<dish>
    <type> Breakfast </type>
    <title> Recipe Title </title>
    <duration> minutes </duration>
    <calories> calories </calories>
    <ingredients>
        <item>Ing. 1</item>
        <item>Ing. 2</item>
    </ingredients>
    <image> image url </image>
    <description>
        <step> step 1 </step>
        <step> step 2 </step>
    </description>
</dish>
```

Here is where the xml file gets called to display the ingredients. However, I realize I'm calling the ingredients tag itself and not iterating through it; so the ingredients displays as empty. I'm not sure how to call each element in the array to display them, I've tried several different ways

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let resultsVC = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ResultsViewController") as! ResultsViewController

    // Information to be passed to ResultsViewController
    resultsVC.getTitle = tableViewDataSource[indexPath.row].title
    resultsVC.getDuration = tableViewDataSource[indexPath.row].duration

    resultsVC.getIngredients = tableViewDataSource[indexPath.row].ingredients

    // Push to next view
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(resultsVC, animated: true)
}
```

The same is true for the description tag as well. Help is appreciated

Comment: what have you tried? what about `for item in tableViewDataSource[indexPath.row].ingredients { print(item) }`

Comment: Sorry for a late response, but it doesn't work. Looks like that gets each character item that is placed in `<ingredients>` but not the characters in `<item>`